TCL error "Child process exited abnormally"
my_file.tcl
set  ...

puts "HELLO_1"
puts [my_pkg::whoami]
puts "HELLO_2"

my_pkg.tcl
namespace eval :: my_pkg{

namespace export  whoami

....

proc :: my_pkg::whoami{} {
set::my_pkg::RUN_1
.....

....


When executed the above, I am getting this error

Child process exited abnormally

How to fix this, can you please suggest workaround for this?

"whoami" is not a tcl keyword, in LINUX it returns the user ID of the account.
So, basically it tells that user is trying to access that pakcage "my_pkg", but it is unsuccessful.
HELLO_1 is appearing
HELLO_2 is not appearing in the log

Hi and welcome. Your code examples are a little bit incomplete. Can you please provide a simplified example of what is happening, and how you are running your code?

Were there any other error messages as well? Those tend to be helpful...

It appears you have spaces in the wrong places:
namespace eval :: my_pkg{

proc :: my_pkg::whoami{} { set::my_pkg::RUN_1 .....

Tcl is very sensitive to whitespace: it is a word-oriented language, so you have to be careful.

The :: must be cuddled up with the name
you must have a space before {

With that proc invocation, we are defining a procedure named :: which takes one argument that is stored in the variable named my_pkg::whoami{} -- that will fail with an error because that is not a valid name for a proc parameter.
You need
namespace eval ::my_pkg {
# ..............^^.....^

proc ::my_pkg::whoami {} { set::my_pkg::RUN_1 .....
# ....^^.............^

See the 12 rules of Tcl.
